# Alternative way to resize image in Azure Function (imageResizer not working)

Tags: c#, azure-functions, imageresizer

I'm trying to resize an image that I get from a remote url but apparently I've had no luck yet.

Using System.Drawing I get an error (probably sandbox related) and using imageResizer it will give me an error

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment' from assembly 'System.Web
```

What can be a easy solution just to get a stream (or byte[]), resize and output the resized image?

Answer (score 0):

Use Nugets not system.drawing. 
Here is the full example:

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/auto-generate-thumbnails-using-an-azure-function-and-azure-blob-storage/

And this one uses Event Grid
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event.md